# Which agencies and which part to get training data for passports, id cards and licenses

Tags: machine-learning

I am interested in doing some research relating to computer vision and passports, id cards and licenses.

I have reached out to several agencies seeking data I would use as training data but keep running into dead ends.

Who would you start with for this data?

Comment: That sounds like a classified to me because these agencies do not give out for that kind of data.